# Boolean Difference with Bevels

Tags: modifiers

I'm new to Blender, and have run into an issue with creating a boolean difference on two objects that both have bevels.  As a test, I start with a simple cube and bevel 4 edges.

I then duplicate the object, resize it, and boolean difference the smaller one from inside the larger.

This works as expected, and I then resized the z-dimension to make it shorter.  I duplicated the original cube and placed on the other.

I now want to take the top one and boolean difference it against the bottom cube, so I move it into position as shown:

[image]

This is where the problem occurs.  At this point, if I boolean difference the top object, it doesn't work.  It leaves me with the result shown here:

[image]

This is probably something simple, but I can't find a reference anywhere on what's going on or how to fix it.  I'm also experiencing the same thing when I try to boolean difference text on an object face.  The issues seem to be the same in both cases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Boolean usually is **an approximation of the result** you are expecting. It has some flaws by default and has a hard time dealing with two geometries that **perfectly overlap, non-manifold geometry, etc.** It also has a hard time dealing with **n-gons** which often occur on beveled meshes and meshed text-objects.

A good way to start is **feeding triangulated geometry into the boolean modifier** and leaving **a good amount of space** in between the meshes you are trying to difference from one another. This way the geometry is unique and cannot be interpreted in multiple ways by the boolean modifier.

I personally look at boolean as the absolute last method to achieve any desired geometry. I only use it if any other solution fails. It does not output clean and predictable geometry and usually needs a considerable amount of clean up.

e.g. you could solve your first shape like this:

[image]